# Container shifting up when text is on two lines

Tags: html, css

So if you look at the 2nd image, it shifts up when the text under spans onto two lines. Maybe this is to do something with the div containers that I'm missing? Can't seem to find the right solution. I'm not super HTML savvy but I'm sure this is a simple fix? ..help!

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix54j.jpg)

```css
 #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 
 .thumb {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17.6%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  
 }
 .thumb p {
  font-family: "Helvetica", helvetica;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin: 0.5em;
 }
 .thumb img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0px;">

<div id="wrapper">
 <h1>GALLERY</h1>
 <h2>LENDING LIBRARY</h2>
 
 <a id="Altamont Wet WR" class="thumb" href="openwindow-https://www.urbanelectricco.com/altamontwall.html">
  <img src="thumbs/altamontwall_mtn.jpg" />
  <p>Altamont Wet WR</p>
  <hr>
  <h3>'Kromezone' Powder Coat, Clear Glass</h3>
 </a> 
 
 
 <a id="Archibald" class="thumb" href="openwindow-https://www.urbanelectricco.com/archibald.html">
  <img src="thumbs/archibald_mtn.jpg" />
  <p>Archibald WR</p>
  <hr>
  <h3>Bronze Finish, Clear Glass & Black Finish, Clear Glass
  </h3>
 </a> 
 
 
 <a id="Belle Meade" class="thumb" href="openwindow-https://www.urbanelectricco.com/bellemeade.html">
  <img src="thumbs/bellemeade_mtn.jpg" />
  <p>Belle Meade WL</p>
  <hr>
  <h3>Vintage Finish</h3>
 </a>
 
 <a id="Belle Meade Double" class="thumb" href="openwindow-https://www.urbanelectricco.com/bellemeadedouble.html">
  <img src="thumbs/bellemeadedouble_mtn.jpg" />
  <p>Belle Meade Double WL</p>
  <hr>
  <h3>Polished Nickel Finish</h3>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way of getting the alignment to be the same across all of the thumbnails is add the following to the .thumb class:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

The reason why the issue arises is that the standard vertical alignment for any div is baseline (right at the bottom). When your text goes onto a second line, it naturally increases the height of that element (and is double the height of all of the other  tags) and pushes everything else in that particular div upwards.

Hope that helps!